# Pass the name of the function and arguments as a string via JSON to the server, and call that function on the server

Tags: javascript, json, function

I have a client-server connection via websocket that communicate with JSON objects. My server has several functions:

```
function FirstFunction(arg1, arg2) {
    ...
}

function SecondFuction(argOther) {
    ...
}
```

How could my client send a JSON object that contains the name of the function I want to call plus the parameters, and make the server call that function? Something like this (pseudo-code, doesn't work)

`data = {"method" : "FirstFunction", "params" : {"arg1" : 10, "arg2" : 20} }`

```
result = data["mehod"](data.params.arg1, data.params.arg2)
```

The reason I want to do it this way is because my client uses Python and my server Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a big security issue, but if that's not a problem for you here's how you can do it:

```js
function FirstFunction(arg1, arg2) { /* ... */ }
function SecondFunction(argOther) { /* ... */ }

const functions = {
  FirstFunction,
  SecondFunction
}

// You didn't specify how you receive the JSON
// so I'm just going to hard code it
const jsonString = `{"method" : "FirstFunction", "params" : {"arg1" : 10, "arg2" : 20} }`

function callFunction (json) {
  const { method, params } = JSON.parse(json)
  functions[method](...params)
}

callFunction(jsonString)
```

Note: The example is case sensitive

The trick here is assigning the functions you want to make available to the client as properties of an object which can be accessed with strings.

Comment: Thank you, it works! May I ask, why would this be a big security issue? What might happen? In this case the connection will only be local. I have some functions that I need to run in JS to fetch some data but I'm doing the app in Python, so I'm creating a client in Python and the server in JS to pass data between them in the same machine. I'm building this for a website, might this still be a security issue? Thank you!

Comment: Well for one any malicious attacker may pass a bogus string, which when invoked would crash the server; another possible issue may be the exposed `Object.prototype` functions, which can be accessed this way. In general exposing functions directly is a bad idea, you always want something between your raw functions and the outside world. Of course all of this doesn't apply if this is just a home project.